# jqGrid frozen:true creating an overlapping duplicate column

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with 10 columns and when I freeze(frozen:true) on first column, it actually puts a horizontal scroll bar into columns header div before data is even loaded AND when data is loaded, there is actually two columns worth of data on top of one another, in the first column.  You can see the duplicate because the formatting of duplicate is offset as if it had different style.
When I freeze first two columns, the horizontal scroll bar is only in 2nd column header, but now the 1st and 2nd columns have duplicates.  As I freeze more columns, the last frozen column has the scroll bar and all the columns have duplicates.

I know this is long, but in instead of image I wanted to detail issues.

The freezing of the columns does work per se, but it causes the issues mentioned above.

Any ideas?

Added image.

[image http://www.nvsninc.com/frozen2.jpg](http://www.nvsninc.com/frozen2.jpg)

update: I discovered after looking at resulting html, the reason for duplicate columns is that there were two divs, one had the columns without freeze and one with column freeze.

update: It turns out the height of the rows in the frozen column is not being set to same height of rows of unfrozen column, so rows from both columns is being seen.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? If you use an old jqGrid you can try to change the URLs to all jqGrid files to free jqGrid URLs described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). Free jqGrid in the fork of jqGrid, which I develop. I made a lot of fixes in frozen columns part.

Comment: Using version 4.5.2.

Comment: Do you tried to change the URLs and to repeat your tests?

Comment: I dowloaded 5.0.2 and getting same issue.

Comment: **I wrote you about free jqGrid (4.12.1) not not about Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.0.2**. I posted you the link to [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). What you need is just change 3 lines on the page, so that you use for example `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.12.1/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css`, `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.12.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.min.js` and `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.12.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js`. It's all.

Comment: I will update to free jqGrid as soon as I can. But in mean time I added more to issue above.

Comment: Sorry, but changing of 3 lines of HTML code takes some seconds. You **don't need to update** all your local files for one test only. You need just use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.12.1/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">`, `<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.12.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.12.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>` **instead of** the references to your local files. You can do this on one HTML page of your old existing application.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I tried your suggestion and still did not work.  It appears the height of the frozen column rows is not being set to height of the unfrozen column underneath so I see the rows from both. Is this a failure of the freeze or is there a property to set or command to execute to fix?

Comment: Can you provide the demo which reproduce the problem? If I can reproduce and debug the problem then I can fix the bug of free jqGrid or to fix your code.

Comment: I finally fixed the issue.  There were two problems, the first was the data below the frozen columns was showing through becase there was not background color or image. Fixed.  The second was the height of rows was auto so it caused the frozen column cells to be incorrect height.  Fixed this with a little method to adjust height that was in another post of yours.  I do appreciate your quick responses and answers.

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear for me **whether some issue exist in free jqGrid or not**. You wrote about some fixes. Do you mean that you found some problems *in your code* or in the code of free jqGrid? Could you describe the origin of the problem more exact? (the code of free jqGrid or your code). If some problem exist in free jqGrid then I would ask you to share the demo which reproduce the problem.